# oracle partition active condition on table

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have oracle query that i want to analyse. The table `track_table` has `active` partition. I dont have that much knowledge about partitioning. I want to check on what conditions this partitioning has been created. To check whether my table is partitioned or not i used below query and it says the `PARTITION_NAME` is active for `track_table` table.

```
SELECT * FROM dba_tab_partitions WHERE table_name = 'track_table';
```

Below is the query which i want to analyse:

```
select count(*) as cnt 
from track_table partition (active) 
where trg_id > 198754
      and status not in (2);
```

Comment: You cannot see the table definition? Use the schema browser of your tool(Toad, sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper) to see the DDL/script of the table. There is a partition section and you'll see the partition definition.

Comment: I cant check from any tool. The table resides in remote database and i dont have permission to view it in oracle sql developer or any other tool. Its only posible through query.

Comment: `active` is a partition of the table. So, your question is what is the condition for data in this partition?

Comment: See here a discussion about getting ddl over dblink https://community.oracle.com/thread/1982552?tstart=0.

Comment: my question is not relevant to the discussion u send . I dont want to know ddl over dblink. I want to know more information(DDL) on which partition active has been created

Comment: It is relevant because if you have the ddl, you'll see the partition definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partition seems to be a list partition. Or maybe is range, almost sure not hash. You can see in the user_tab_partitions in the high_value column the values for which is built the partition.

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_partitions@your_dblink_name WHERE table_name = 'TRACK_TABLE';
```

Otherwise, if you want more, see this discusssion: [Getting schema (DDL) of a table through DB link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1982552?tstart=0)

Comment: its a list partition. But still it doesnt answer my question. I want to know what does list partition means ? And on which condition means whats the criteria to make partition on track_table ?

Comment: You'll find what a list partition means by searching on the internet, or consulting the documentation. What is the criteria for your table it is exactly what I answered. See the result of the query and you'll know how the table is partitioned.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.  I'm not sure that it's working.

```
declare
h       NUMBER;         
th      NUMBER;        
doc     CLOB;         
BEGIN
 h := DBMS_METADATA.OPEN(object_type => 'TABLE',network_link => 'dblink' );
 DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(h,'SCHEMA','schema_name');
 DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(h,'NAME','table_name');
 th := DBMS_METADATA.ADD_TRANSFORM(h,'DDL');
 DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(th,'SQLTERMINATOR',true);
 LOOP
   doc := DBMS_METADATA.FETCH_CLOB(h);
   EXIT WHEN doc IS NULL;
   dbms_output.put_line(doc);
   exit;
 END LOOP;
 DBMS_METADATA.CLOSE(h);
end;
```

Comment: its givign an error PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'DBLINK'
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_METADATA@DBLINK' must be declared

Comment: Hi, if you got the code from [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1982552?tstart=0) then pls update the answer with the source. If it is your code, ignore my comment.